# How to define a route with loadChildren property (lazy) inside an Angular library?

Tags: angular

We have a large Angular 8 app that we want to split into several parts (libraries). We would like each library to define its own routes without losing lazy-loading ability. But we are facing compilation error.

Library routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/demo/demo.module').then(m => m.DemoModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'app1',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
];

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyLibraryRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the first error we ran into:

> Lambda not supported

This is the reason why we added the `// @dynamic` flag. But then we got the following error:

> "ERROR: You must set "output.dir" instead of "output.file" when generating multiple chunks."

And we don't clearly understand the point.

I came across [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31893#issuecomment-516615243) from Google staff which suggests that we are doing something wrong...

Could anyone confirm and ideally explain why that it is definitively no way to define lazy-routes from a library?

Comment: Hy Remi, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not... Lazy loading routes must be defined at application level and not at library level.

Comment: I personnaly use an intermediary "RoutingModule" for each libraries that only import the child module (routes definitions are only in library). And I lazy-load this intermediary module.

Comment: Interesting... I'd like to keep routes definitions inside libraries and it seems that it's that you do. Did you have any code sample to illustrate the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { ApplicationModule } from './application.module';
...
export function getAppModule() {
    return ApplicationModule;
}
...
loadChildren: getAppModule
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your solution, what is that supposed to do? Could your explain?

Comment: @RemiPatriarche If you heed to load module that is installed to node_modules and support --aot build this is correct way.

Comment: @KuzenkoLubko am I wrong or does this solution no longer lazy load in the module? 
 In other words, "demo" module from above would not be lazy loaded using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that is mentioned for dynamic import, in the newer version of angular. But anyways the old syntax still works in the newer versions of angular too.

Try this..

```
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomeModule',
},
```

If you would like to use the old syntax, then use this article --> https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-lazy-load-module-example/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately and unless I am mistaken, this article is about how to lazy-load modules at the APP level not at LIBRARY level. We have no problem to define lazy routes at application level, the error occurs when we try to define lazy-routes at the library level. I hope I have clarified our situation.